# Como passar uma função para outro componente através de props?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou tentando fazer um todolist com React e no momento tenho dois componentes: O TodoListApp e TodoForm. No TodoListApp tenho uma função que adiciona um valor em uma lista que está no state, mas esse valor vem de outro componente: o TodoForm.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vou colocar o código dos dois:

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoForm from '../components/TodoForm';

export default class TodoListApp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TodoForm pushToItems={this.pushToItems}></TodoForm>
    );
  }


 //Tento passar esta função para o outro componente
  pushToItems = (todo) => {
    this.setState({
      items: [...this.state.items, todo]
    });
  }
}
```

Componente de apresentação:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class TodoForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todo: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  //Chamo a função que vem do outro componente através das props.
  onAdd = () => {
    this.props.pushToItems(this.state.todo);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="todo" placeholder="Enter todo here"
         onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onAdd}>Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

O que está acontecendo é que quando clico no botão de adicionar um todo, ele me retorna:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.pushToItems is not a function

Como se o componente todoform não estivesse recebendo a função como prop.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o problema. Criei um [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-dawn-3fv8z?fontsize=14), mas está funcionando...

Comment: @LuizFelipe E aqui continua nessa.... https://prnt.sc/obggs6

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema ocorre por que o contexto é quebrado, você pode ler mais [aqui](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/). Resumidamente, SEMPRE utilize `bind` no construtor para todas as suas funções:

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

   this.state = {
     todo: ''
   }
 }
```

Isso é uma chatice. Felizmente, [Hooks](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) elimina esse - e muitos outros - problema por não utilizar classes.

Answer (score 0):

Na hora de passar a função como props para outro componente, tente fazer desta forma:

```
  <TodoForm pushToItems={this.pushToItems.bind(this)}></TodoForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Você pode no filho usar :

```
this.props.NomeDaFunc(Parametro1)
```

No pai você usa:

```
<SeuComponente NomedaFunc={ this.NomeDaFunc.bind(this) } />
```

Ele vai executar ela normalmente, isso é algo interessante se você quiser mudar um estado do pai de dentro de uma filha, como também usar Func. de validação de dentro dela.